# problem multisite with blog id

Tags: php, shortcode, blog-id

I have a little problem that I can not solve.
I have a website "multi-site" system with ADS PRO scripteo.
I wish I could enter leaderboard banner.

After that I created the shortcode:

```
[bsa_pro_ad_space id=2]
```

At this point I give shortcode in php code:

```
<?php


if(do_shortcode('[bsa_pro_ad_space id=2]')) {
    echo '
      <div id="bnftr">
'.do_shortcode('[bsa_pro_ad_space id=2]').'
      </div>';
} else {
    echo '
      <div id="bnftr-none"></div>';
}
```

this works well.

The problem is this:
since in a subdomain the banner will have a ads and in another subdomain banner should have a different banner and not the same throughout the network.

I wrote the code this way:

```
<?php


if ( get_current_blog_id() = 1 ) {

if(do_shortcode('[bsa_pro_ad_space id=1]')) {
    echo '
      <div id="bnftr">
'.do_shortcode('[bsa_pro_ad_space id=1]').'
      </div>';
} else {
    echo '
      <div id="bnftr-none"></div>';
}

} elseif ( get_current_blog_id() = 2 ) {

if(do_shortcode('[bsa_pro_ad_space id=2]')) {
    echo '
      <div id="bnftr">
'.do_shortcode('[bsa_pro_ad_space id=2]').'
      </div>';
} else {
    echo '
      <div id="bnftr-none"></div>';
}

}
```

when I update the page home page remains black screen. you only see the logo.
(I wish the blog ID 1 there is a banner, and the blog ID 2, another banner)

can someone help me !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, you're assigning values to get_current_blog_id instead of comparing them. That is

```
get_current_blog_id() = 1
```

should be

```
get_current_blog_id() === 1
```

in both places.